# Adding multiple items in a Panel At Once

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

just a short :)

I have

```
        panel8.add(label4).setVisible(true);
        panel8.add(panel4).setVisible(true);
        panel8.add(button1).setVisible(true);
        panel8.add(panel7).setVisible(true);
```

But I want to have something like this:

```
    panel8.add(label4, panel4, button1, panel7).setVisible(true);
```

How is the correct syntax? Or isn't it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Give your class a method that allows this to happen. 2) Don't directly interact with another class's fields as that way lies madness.

Comment: Also, no need to call `setVisible(...)` like you're doing. A component's visible property is true by default, and so you only need to call this on the top-level window after adding all components.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to give "panel8" its own class, MySomethingPanel, and give it its own components there. As an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Also you should avoid using trivial variable names such as `Button1` unless they are being used for trivial purposes such as the index of a for loop. Instead use names that have some meaning so that your code becomes self-commenting.

Comment: first of all, thanks for adding the tag. Now to the vars and fields. They shall only be used the moment i need them and vanish and get overwritten after a single click. I need none of them any longer than a single click, so i decided that way, but I'm a totally newbie in Java OOP. The Var-Names will be changed immediately, thanks for that

Comment: `"Now to the vars and fields. They shall only be used the moment i need them and vanish and get overwritten after a single click."` -- this makes no difference, and is no reason to throw out OOP principles.

Comment: roger that, will change it :)

Comment: The short answer is no...

Comment: that easy @MadProgrammer? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is, no, you can't do that, it's not how the API is designed.

You could create a utility method which could do it though, maybe something like...

```
public JComponent addTo(JComponent parent, JComponent... children) {
    if (children != null && children.length > 0) {
        for (JComponent child : children) {
            parent.add(child);
        }
    }
    return parent;
}
```

which you might be able to use something like...

```
addTo(Panel8, 
    GamulatorMain.Label4, 
    GamulatorMain.Panel4, 
    GamulatorMain.Button1, 
    GamulatorMain.Panel7).setVisible(true);
```

as an example

Comment: It's just one approach, which doesn't require inheritance to achieve

Answer (score 2):

Some observations from your code:

1. You're seem to be accessing global, static variables, that's a no-no
2. Your variables start with an upper-case, that's non-standard in Java
3. Please don't use numbers for multiple panels (`panel4`, `panel8`, ...). Instead name them according to what they are (e.g. `buttonPanel`, `outputPanel`...)

Instead, you'd be better off creating a custom class for the `Panel8` container, e.g:

```
public class MyPanel extends Panel {
    public MyPanel() {
        //...instantiate label4
        add(label4);
        //...instantiate panel4
        add(panel4);
        //...instantiate button1
        add(button1);
        //...instantiate panel7
        add(panel7);
    }
}
```

Comment: exactly that is my problem :(

Comment: @Ekonion: no, your problem is that your code needs to be completely re-designed and use OOP principles.

Comment: @Ekonion: and while the method chaining above may be incorrect, the other points below are spot-on.

Comment: You're right. Shame on me. I could've sworn I've chained like that in the past. Let me fix the answer...

Comment: by the way, that is not what i asked for. I Asked for something similiar to dovetalks answer

Comment: @Ekonion: you sometimes get *more* than you asked for when you post code and questions here. Best to try to learn from it.